# Libgdx Stencil Buffer overlap

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, stencil-buffer

I have a question about using the Stencil Buffer with OpenGL and libgdx

As example I need to draw to circles with overlap.

The code of render method is here:

```
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);

    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    Gdx.gl.glClearStencil(0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glStencilFunc(GL20.GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glStencilOp(GL20.GL_KEEP, GL20.GL_INCR, GL20.GL_INCR);

    shapeRenderer.setColor(new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f)); // red
    shapeRenderer.circle(200, 200, 100);
    shapeRenderer.circle(180, 180, 100);

    Gdx.gl.glStencilFunc(GL20.GL_EQUAL, 2, 0xFF);
    Gdx.gl.glStencilOp(GL20.GL_REPLACE, GL20.GL_REPLACE, GL20.GL_REPLACE);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(new Color(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f)); // green
    shapeRenderer.circle(200, 200, 100);
    shapeRenderer.circle(180, 180, 100);

    Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    shapeRenderer.end();
```

Result is:

[image: result]

Expected something like this:

[image: expected]

Overlap should be in other color.
What is a problem here?

Comment: Does replacing `Gdx.gl.glStencilOp(GL20.GL_REPLACE, GL20.GL_REPLACE, GL20.GL_REPLACE);` with `GL_KEEP` for all arguments change something?

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but nothing changed.

Comment: So, any progress on this one?

Answer (score 1):

The logic looks OK as far as it goes, so I suspect the issue is that your framebuffer that you are rendering in to doesn't actually have a stencil attachment. If there is no stencil buffer OpenGL ES behaves as if the stencil test is disabled, so your final two circles will always overdraw the first two.

Check your context creation (for window surfaces), or your FBO creation for off-screen render targets.

Comment: Thanks, will check it.

Comment: Thanks. by default libgdx has a disabled stencil buffer (at least for desktop). To enable it `config.setBackBufferConfig(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 1, 0)` is required in DesktopLauncher.